# Mongoose virtual environment doesn't appear in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have added a virtual environment for reviews but for some reason it doesn't appear in postman when i try to get it. If worked correctly it should display reviews with a value of null. I am fairly new to this but i did read through the mongoose documentation and other online sources but everything seems similar to what i wrote.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const slugify = require('slugify');

const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Name required'],
    unique: true,
    maxlength: [40, 'Less then or equal to 40 characters'],
    minlength: [10, 'More then or equal to 10 characters'],
  },
  slug: String,
  duration: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Duration required'],
  },
  maxGroupSize: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Group size required'],
  },
  difficulty: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Difficulty required'],
    enum: {
      values: ['easy', 'medium', 'difficult'],
      message: 'Difficulty is either easy, medium, difficult',
    },
  },
  ratingsAverage: {
    type: Number,
    default: 4.5,
    max: [5, 'Less than or equal to 5'],
    min: [1, 'More than or equal to 1'],
  },
  ratingsQuantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Price required'],
  },
  priceDiscount: {
    type: Number,
    validate: {
      validator: function (val) {
        // This only points to current doc on New doc creating
        return val < this.price ? true : false;
      },
      message: 'Discount should be less than the regular price',
    },
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Summary required'],
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  imageCover: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Image required'],
  },
  images: [String],
  createAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
  startDates: [Date],
  secretTour: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  startLocation: {
    // GeoJSON (At least 2 field names e.g. type and coordinates)
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "Point",
      enum: ["Point"]
    },
    coordinates: [Number],
    address: String,
    description: String,
  },
  locations: [{
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: "Point",
      enum: ["Point"],
    },
    coordinates: [Number],
    address: String,
    description: String,
    day: Number
  }],
  guides: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }]
}, {
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});

tourSchema.virtual('durationWeeks').get(function () {
  return this.duration / 7;
});

// Virtual populate
tourSchema.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Review',
  foreignField: 'tour',
  localField: '_id',
});
```

Here is the controller for the tour

```js
const Tour = require('../models/tourModel');
const APIFeatures = require('../utils/apiFeatures');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const AppError = require('../utils/appError');
const {
  deleteOne,
  updateOne,
  createOne
} = require("./handlerFactory")

const {
  populate
} = require('../models/tourModel');

const aliasTopTours = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.limit = '5';
  req.query.sort = '-ratingAverage,price';
  req.query.fields = 'name, price, ratingAverage, summary, difficulty';
  next();
});

const getAllTours = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Execute query
  const features = new APIFeatures(Tour.find(), req.query)
    .filter()
    .sort()
    .limit()
    .pagination();
  const tours = await features.query;
  // Send response
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    length: tours.length,
    message: tours,
  });
});

const getTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const tourId = await (await Tour.findById(req.params.Id)).populate('reviews');
  if (!tourId) {
    return next(new AppError('No tour found with that ID', 404));
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    data: {
      tourId,
    },
  });
});

const postTour = createOne(Tour)

const patchTour = updateOne(Tour)

const deleteTour = deleteOne(Tour)

const getTourStats = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const stats = await Tour.aggregate([{
      $match: {
        ratingAverage: {
          $gte: 4.5,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$difficulty',
        aveRating: {
          $avg: '$ratingAverage',
        },
        avePrice: {
          $avg: '$price',
        },
        minPrice: {
          $min: '$price',
        },
        maxPrice: {
          $max: '$price',
        },
        totalRating: {
          $sum: '$ratingQuantity',
        },
        totalTours: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        avePrice: 1,
      },
    },
  ]);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    message: stats,
  });
});

const getMonthlyPlan = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const year = req.params.year * 1;
  const plan = await Tour.aggregate([{
      $unwind: '$startDates',
    },
    {
      $match: {
        startDates: {
          $gte: new Date(`${year}-01-01`),
          $lte: new Date(`${year}-12-31`),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          $month: '$startDates',
        },
        numTourStarts: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
        tours: {
          $push: '$name',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        month: '$_id',
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        numTourStarts: -1,
      },
    },
    {
      $limit: 12,
    },
  ]);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    length: plan.length,
    message: plan,
  });
});

module.exports = {
  getAllTours,
  getTour,
  postTour,
  patchTour,
  deleteTour,
  aliasTopTours,
  getTourStats,
  getMonthlyPlan,
};
```

Comment: Can you show the controller function also.

Comment: @SudarakaSenevirathne here you go. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const tourId = await (await Tour.findById(req.params.Id)).populate('reviews');
```

The problem is here, you need to remove one await here, no need to use 2 await in this line

Comment: omg how did I not see it. Thank you so much its working now.